# 'begin' was not declared in this scope

Tags: qt, c++11, iterator

I have a class like that (I leave only the relevant part):

```
    template<class T>
    class MyList
    {
    public:
    // ....

    typename QList<T*>::iterator begin()
    {
        return list.begin();
    }

    typename QList<T*>::iterator end()
    {
        return list.end();
    }

    typename QList<T*>::iterator skip(int n)
        {
            auto ite = list.begin();

            while(n --> 0)
                ++ite;

            return ite;
        }

       QList<T*> list;
    };
```

when I went to use the class:

```
MyList<Foo*> foo;
for(Foo* f : foo.skip(1)) {
```

I get this error:

> 'begin' was not declared in this scope

I remove `skip()` call, the loop works fine... I don't understand why. Why that and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just how range-based for loops work in C++. In particular, when in a range expression the participant is a class type, in your case `MyList`, for the expression to be legitimate the class type must have defined members `begin` and `end`.

Member function `MyList::skip` returns an iterator to a `QList<T*>`. This iterator class doesn't define any `begin` and `end` members and the compiler renders this type (i.e., the iterator) not a legitimate participant for a range-based for loop expression while the class type `MyList` that has defined members `begin` and `end` renders legitimate.

More info on how a range-for loop works you can find [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

Comment: I made confusing between C++'s and Qt's iterator